# JIRA SOAP createIssue from C#

Tags: web-services, jira

Has anyone had trouble with response of JIRA's createIssue method?
The problem is, that method returns empty attachmentName node:

```
<attachmentNames soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[0]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array"/>
```

which is actually ok, but then the deserialization to the RemorteIssue object fails with:

Error in call to JiraService, method createIssue. There is an error in XML document (1, 802).. The specified type was not recognized: name='string', namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', at .

part of the RemoteIssue looks like this:

```
  [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute("RemoteIssue", "http://beans.soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com")]
  public class RemoteIssue : AbstractRemoteEntity 
  {

    /// <remarks/>
    public RemoteVersion[] affectsVersions;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string assignee;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string[] attachmentNames;

    /// <remarks/>
    public RemoteComponent[] components;
```

The RemoteIssue however is created, the only problem is, I can't get RemoteIssue returned which contains the key to the newly created issue

Comment: Have you tried this using "Add Service Reference"? It's more likely to work than an ASMX client will.

Comment: I did "Add Web Reference" if I understand you correct. And after using the generated code, parsing the response to the RemoteIssue object fails with InvalidOperationException. Here's part of the stacktrace:

System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='string', namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', at <attachmentNames xmlns=''>.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.GetPrimitiveType(XmlQualifiedName typeName, Boolean throwOnUnknown)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadArray(String typeName, String typeNs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a tool to interact with Jira and it is able to create new issues perfectly. If you want, you can take a look in http://github.com/adrianoc/binboo

Comment: Thanx, I will accept that as an answer, altough my problem is long solved and living in production with parsing an XML :)